# Php Striping out sections in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

I have a string that will be coming in like this: Var1-Var2-Var3-Var4

*note Var is just a example the real string that will be coming in will be different every time. The only thing is the dashes. The dashes however will not be in the same spot everytime either. 
Real life ex. PPC-Google-Test-Paid

So pretty much what I am trying to do is assign the string coming in to different variables. like this:

```
$a=Var1-Var2
$b = Var3
$c = Var4
```

or

```
$a=PPC-Google
$b = Test
$c = Paid
```

The first two vars will go to $a and the last two vars will go to $b and $c. Now again remember that Vars won't actually be there, it will be different text every time in place of the vars.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already?

Comment: You should split the string along the `-`'s and then concat the first two when assigning to $a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php function [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can do what you want.

```
$str = "Var1-Var2-Var3-Var4";
$arr = explode("-", $str);
$a = $arr[0]."-".$arr[1];
$b = $arr[2];
$c = $arr[3];
```